# Converting an HTML result into a float

Tags: python-3.x

My program is a basic web scraper which will return a price for a given card input. However, I would like to convert the HTML result I receive from the scraper into a float to perform mathematical operations with it. Currently, my code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

number = int(input("Enter the amount of cards: "))
card_list = {}
for i in range(number):
    card_names = input("Enter the card name: ")
    set_names = input("Enter the respective card set: ")
    card_list[card_names] = set_names

for card_name, set_name in card_list.items():
    url = "https://www.mtggoldfish.com/price/"+set_name+"/"+card_name+"#paper"
    page = requests.get(url)
    page_content = page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find_all("div", {'class':"price-box-container"})
    for t in table:
        paper = t.find_all("div",{"class":"price-box paper"})
        prices = t.findChildren("div",{"class":"price-box paper"})
        for price in prices:
            print(price.get_text())
```

Normally, it returns something like `PAPER 69.78`, but trying to cut out the "PAPER" using `prices = prices[1:]` doesn't return any result. Also,trying `float:prices` returns:
`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ResultSet'`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I had a look at the URL you are trying to scrape. Why don't you just look for the specific price element instead the parent div?
Like 
```price_div = t.findChildren("div",{"class":"price-box-price"})```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

number = int(input("Enter the amount of cards: "))
card_list = {}
for i in range(number):
    card_names = input("Enter the card name: ")
    set_names = input("Enter the respective card set: ")
    card_list[card_names] = set_names

for card_name, set_name in card_list.items():
    url = "https://www.mtggoldfish.com/price/"+set_name+"/"+card_name+"#paper"
    page = requests.get(url)
    page_content = page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find_all("div", {'class':"price-box-container"})
    for t in table:
        paper = t.find_all("div",{"class":"price-box paper"})
        prices = t.findChildren("div",{"class":"price-box paper"})
        price_box_type = prices[0].find("div", class_="price-box-type").get_text(strip=True)
        price_box_price = prices[0].find("div", class_="price-box-price").get_text(strip=True)
        print(f"price-box-type - {price_box_type}")
        print(f"price-box-price - {price_box_price}")
```

Output:

```
Enter the amount of cards: 1
Enter the card name: Fiery+Emancipation
Enter the respective card set: Core+Set+2021
price-box-type - PAPER
price-box-price - 9.87

Enter the amount of cards: 1
Enter the card name: Ereboss+Intervention
Enter the respective card set: Theros+Beyond+Death
price-box-type - PAPER
price-box-price - 0.50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

number = int(input("Enter the amount of cards: "))
card_list = {}
for i in range(number):
    card_names = input("Enter the card name: ")
    set_names = input("Enter the respective card set: ")
    card_list[card_names] = set_names

for card_name, set_name in card_list.items():
    url = "https://www.mtggoldfish.com/price/"+set_name+"/"+card_name+"#paper"

    page = requests.get(url)
    page_content = page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find_all("div", {'class':"price-box-container"})
    for t in table:
        paper = t.find_all("div",{"class":"price-box paper"})
        prices = t.findChildren("div",{"class":"price-box paper"})
        price_box_type = prices[0].find("div", class_="price-box- 
type").get_text(strip=True)
        price_box_price = float(prices[0].find("div", class_="price-box- 
price").get_text(strip=True))
        print(f"price-box-price - {price_box_price}")
        print(type(price_box_price)) #just for reference
```

Output:

```
Enter the amount of cards: 1
Enter the card name: Baneslayer+Angel
Enter the respective card set: Core+Set+2021
price-box-price - 2.92
<class 'float'>
```